# c++ mac/m1/intel how to get cpu architecture?

Tags: c++, macos, architecture, arm, apple-m1

I need to find out at runtime which architecture the cpu is running.
I've so far used qt : `QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture()` but there is a problem.
The returned value will change when ever I run application that was compiled for x86_64 or arm64. So this will not return the hardware architecture that the system is natively running, but the emulated one by mac. Say if I run x86_64 it would run via rosetta probably and then the arch would be x86_64 and not arm64.

I need a way to find out hardware arch of system that is, and not is emulated...

Does any1 have any idea how to do it?
Macros/etc will not work.

Running QProcess from within the app still returns x86_64 from `uname -p` etc.

Comment: Ok I just realised I can call QProcess and use terminal ```uname -p``` to query it and grab output.

Comment: Kernel state `sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string` might also be useful.

Comment: Also, `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` might be useful.

Comment: Edit, seems like neither of these options will work as Intel application starting QProcess & running terminal command still returns x86_64 instead of arm :/
```ysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string``` does not run on mac as far as the error says. ```system_profiler SPHardwareDataType``` does not say if its x86_64 or arm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting QProcess does not work, he inherits base application architecture.

I found out that apple added a command to figure out if I'm running in "translated" mode, this can then be used as indication if we are on intel or arm.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/about-the-rosetta-translation-environment